# Why is a windows file share not accessible intermittently?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

Setup: Computer A has a file share called "ABC" with full control for a specific user X in the given domain. OS on all machines: Windows Server 2008 R2 with no antivirus software

A service running on Computers B and C logged in as user X need to write to this share "ABC" on computer "A".

From time to time, the share "abc" will be visible only to computer B and not to computer C unless it is rebooted. But the share can be accessed sometimes (again very random) if I use \ipaddress\abc from computer C instead of \hostname\abc.

Also when this happens, we cannot establish a sql server connection from service to computer A from computer C.

SO I have checked the usual suspects from other related questions in this forum:

1. No windows credentials are cached on the target and client computers.
2. nslookup correctly displays the domain controler ip and the target computer's ip.
3. When I run tracert from the client computer, target computer is reached in 1 hop.
4. When I use net view targetcomputer, I get System Error 53. I also flushed and registered dns from the computer C with no success.

I am out of ideas at this point other than rebooting. and I can't rely on rebooting since we can only reboot during maintenance hours. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You need to sniff the traffic from "Computer C" during the outage. This is going to tell you a _lot_ about what's going on. Wireshark will be your friend for this one for sure.

Comment: Is the error you get at point 4 a BSOD error, or something else?

Comment: I ran wireshark on Computer C, but not sure what to look for. Also I created another share on Computer A and I could access it without any problem from computer C. On the wireshark trace, I am getting OBJECT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND for some desktop.ini file. But I got the same trace accessing the other new share too.

Comment: The error I get at point 4 is from cmd line when I issued net view targetcomputer. SO today I restarted computer C and I can view the share on computer A but I cannot view its contents. i.e net use targetcomputer/share can be mapped to a drive. But when I try to access the drive, it errors out.

Comment: I also applied a hotfix as mentioned here on computer C but no luck. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2194664

Comment: One more thing: it is not about this file share alone. I cant open a sql connection either using Sql Server Management Studio from computer C to Computer A.

Comment: Is there anything different about the network topology between computers B and A, and computers C and A?

Comment: Also, when you're having the problem on computer C, can you access shares (and SQL servers if you have others) on computers others than A without any trouble?

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer on A and C during the outages? And do you get an error message if you try to manually map a network drive in windows during these outages? Do A, B, and C run different services (I'm interested in, is one of them a DNS server for any of the others? Are these computers domain joined?) Finally, for clarification, when you've run nslookup, has that been during one of these outages?

Comment: All these computers use a Domain Controller on a separate computer D. Yes when I ran nslookup, it was during the outage.

Comment: Yes, I was able to access other shares from Computer C including a newly created share on Computer A. No errors in the event log.

Comment: I rebooted computer A and C and everything is back to normal now

Comment: During the time you are unable to access the share, try pinging the hostname of the server to see if it resolves to an IP address

Comment: The only time I had such weird problems is when I placed my computers in different VLANs or configured them to use different Gateways, I later realized that the source of all the herror is the Network Location Awareness Service, check it out, this might help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753545(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a DNS issue to me. To confirm, I'd add server name and IP to the hosts file on the computer with issues and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: It seems to be a DNS issue but the ping "hostname " works though. I can access the remote server using ipaddress, so that would mean adding the hosts entry would work. But we do not want to add host entries as there are quite a few servers and they all can talk to each other.